# Сортировка выборки.

Tags: php, mysql

Здрасте. 
Есть таблица. Например выглядит она так

```
    Имя    Сумма

   Петя     1
   Ваня     2
   Коля     1
   Петя     0,5
   Ваня     1
```

Значение столбца "Имя" уникальные. 
Вопрос. Как мне вывести эти значения по порядку, считая сумму каждого значения?
Например:

```
Ваня 3
Петя 1,5
Коля 1
Ваня 1
```

Сейчас у меня просто работает вывод этих всех ребят в цикле. Без сортировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тот результат, который вам требуется, длстигается так называемыми aggregate functions. Я давно не копался в чистом SQL, возможно, этот пример не взлетит.

```
SELECT name, SUM(value)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC
```

Comment: А в ответ мне пишет FUNCTION название_бД.SUM does not exist

Comment: @RattleSneyk, а какая у Вас СУБД?

Comment: СУБД - mysql

Comment: @RattleSneyk, проверьте, чтобы между SUM и скобками не было пробела

Comment: Все. 
Я забыл value во второй строчке поменять на свою=) 
Спс